# Is this layout possible with div's

Tags: html, css, drupal, themes

[image: regions/divs in custom Drupal 7 theme]

This should be the home view on larger screens. 
The DIVS are all regions in my Drupal 7 theme but I'm having trouble with DIV3.
Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with CSS columns in modern browsers, falling back to using the [jQuery Masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) in older browsers.

A full explanation can be found at [Creating a CSS-only Responsive Masonry](http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/)

Comment: Thanks for this one. It solves it without the use of jQuery but can be set as fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Gridster.Js 
http://dsmorse.github.io/gridster.js/

You can manage the dimension in blocks width and height.
You can organize the divs just with a drag and drop (you can disable the drag and drop if you don't need).